# WebDriverIO - Strange behaviour while running on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I have been working with wdio using JavaScript and Cucumber for our project.

Seems like chrome options doesn't seem to have any effect. Chrome browser doesn't start maximised.

```
goog:chromeOptions': {
 args: ['--start-maximized']
}
```

Some where on this site, I saw a person mentioning of using "disable-gpu" to the options, I have tried this as well and there is no effect.

When the script runs, on the browser, the strange behaviour is, it performs each operation by **pinching the screen**. I was wondering, maybe it is due to incompatibility and hence updated every npm package to the latest version, but it still behaves the same way.

Versions used -

```
WebDriver Version: 6.3.5
Chrome Driver Version: 84.0.1
Google Chrome Version: 84.0.4147.105
```

package.json dependencies -

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.3.6",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.3.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.3.6",
    "chromedriver": "^84.0.1",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "^2.2.8",
    "wdio-cucumber-reporter": "0.0.2",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "wdio-firefox-profile-service": "^0.1.3",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.12",
    "wdio-viewport-size": "^1.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
    "webdriverio": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chance": "^1.1.6",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^6.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.18.0",
    "postgres": "^1.0.2",
    "ramda": "^0.27.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "underscore": "^1.10.2",
    "wdio": "^4.0.0",
  }
```

wdio.conf.js file -

```
const cucumberJSON = require('wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter')
const multipleCucumberHtmlReporter = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter')
const moment = require('moment')
const { removeSync } = require('fs-extra')
exports.config = {
  runner: 'local',
  specs: [
    './features/E2E/E2E.feature'
  ],
  exclude: [
  ],
  maxInstances: 10,
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 5,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--start-maximized']
    },
    'cjson:metadata': {
    // For a browser
      browser: {
        name: 'chrome',
        version: '58'
      },
      device: 'HP Elite',
      platform: {
        name: 'windows',
        version: '10'
      }
    }
  }],
  logLevel: 'debug',
  bail: 0,
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  framework: 'cucumber',
  reporters: ['cucumberjs-json'],
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./stepDefinitions/given.js', './stepDefinitions/when.js', './stepDefinitions/then.js'],
    backtrace: true,
    requireModule: [],
    dryRun: false,
    failFast: false,
    format: ['pretty'],
    snippets: true,
    source: true,
    profile: [],
    strict: true,
    tagExpression: '@E2E',
    timeout: 60000,
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false
  },
  onPrepare () {
    removeSync('.tmp/')
    console.log('Starting cucumber tests')
  },

  async afterStep () {
    await browser.takeScreenshot().then((val) => {
      cucumberJSON.default.attach(val, 'image/png')
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error in capturing screenshots', err)
    })
  },

  onComplete () {
    multipleCucumberHtmlReporter.generate({
      openReportInBrowser: true,
      reportName: 'Project Report',
      screenshotPath: './reports/screenshots/',
      displayDuration: true,
      saveCollectedJSON: false,
      jsonDir: '.tmp/json/',
      reportPath: './reports/',
      customData: {
        title: 'Project Data',
        data: [
          { label: 'Project', value: 'Project Value'},
          { label: 'Release', value: '1.0' },
          { label: 'Execution Start Date', value: moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY') }
        ]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help. I have tried a lot ways, but results always remains the same. Maybe I am doing something wrong here. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out, why it doesn't work. I have followed the below steps to resolve. Hope it helps someone out there facing same issue.

1. Performed `npx wdio config`
2. Answered the required questions
3. When it comes to installing services, I chose `chromdriver` instead of `selenium-standalone`
4. Installed all the required packages which includes -
   (Guess you can install these separately as well, I just chose this route to perform)

```
chromedriver
wdio-chromedriver-service
```

5. Replaced my old config with new one and it started working again. It even started the browser in maximised mode.

**Result of the run -**

```
Starting cucumber tests
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.      
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

I really do not know why it should behave like this strangely, since Selenium-standalone does contain the chromeDriver. If anyone knows the answer to this, Please add, would be great to learn!